# Address Sanitizer (aka ASan) does not provide details where memory gets leaked (Unknown module)

Tags: memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

I am debugging a huge codebase written in C, I built my binary using Address Sanitizer to check out potential leaks on the product, here is the result of running the app

```
==2466657==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 6092 byte(s) in 35 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff7e393b990 in operator new[](unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xf1990)

    #1 0x7ff7da86d79e  (<unknown module>)

Direct leak of 28 byte(s) in 7 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7ff7e393b990 in operator new[](unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.5+0xf1990)

    #1 0x7ff7da877f71  (<unknown module>)**

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 6120 byte(s) leaked in 42 allocation(s).
```

As you notice, ASan shows  which does not really help on a huge codebase !
Am looking for ideas and insights about getting details while running ASan ?

Comment: Try compiling your app with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` or set environment variable `export ASAN_OPTIONS=fast_unwind_on_malloc=0` before running it.